# Dynamically Adding a Row with jQuery adds row to bottom of table

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Whenever I add a row to my table using jQuery, the row ends up at the bottom of the table.

My project is using ASP.NET MVC5 and the Bootstrap style.  It is the default project template from VS2013 for MVC apps.

My form looks like this:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserViewModels.First().Email)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserViewModels.First().FirstName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserViewModels.First().LastName)
            </th>
            <th>Actions</th>            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>    
            <td>
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Email" name="Email" type="email" value="" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" value="" />      
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="check-box" id="Active" name="Active" type="checkbox" value="true" />
            </td>   
            <td>
                <input id="addNewUser" type="image" src="/Content/icons/save.png" alt="Create User" title="Create User" />      
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

The jquery script looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addNewUser").click(AddUserListener);
}

function AddUserListener() {
    var postData = {
        Email: $("#Email").val(),
        FirstName: $("#FirstName").val(),
        LastName: $("#LastName").val(),         
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Admin/CreateNewUser',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: postData,
        success: function (data) {
            var newRow = "<tr id='" + data.Id + "'><td>" + data.Email + "</td><td>" + data.FirstName + "</td><td>" + 
                data.LastName + "</td></tr>";

            $(".table:first > tbody:last").prepend(newRow);

            $("#Email").val = "";
            $("#LastName").val = "";
            $("#Active").val = false;
        },
        error: function () {
            //TODO: Add error handling
        }

    }); //End of ajax call
}
```

I have tried a variety of different ways of adding the row to the top of table.  It does correctly add the row to the second tbody, but if that section already contains a row, the new row gets added below it.

It also auto formats the email as an html mailto link.

Is there something in MVC5s default jQuery/Boostrap js files that would cause this, and if so, how do I disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write `$('.table').find('tbody').prepend(newRow);` instead of `$(".table:first > tbody:last").prepend(newRow);`

This will add row at starting of table

see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zpmd2a3g/2/)

Comment: Will that the new record to the top of the second tbody in the table?  I don't think it will.  The problem is not adding the record to the table - it adds fine.  The question is, why does it get added to the bottom

Comment: its because of your selector, see now, i have updated my fiddle in answer you can use selector as `$('.table').find('tbody:last')`

Comment: The selector is fine.  When I use Chromes JS debugger, and put a break point on $("#Email").val = ""; I see the item at the top of the table - exactly where I want it.  When I click run after that, it gets moved to the bottom and reformatted so that the plain text email turns into a hyperlink.  I want to know if there is something in the default JS files bundled with ASP.NET MVC5 that would causing that, and how to disable it

Comment: Than i can say that your another code is affecting your table. look into your code and you will get solution and if your solution is live than give me link so that i can look into it

Comment: I know there is something else affecting it!!!  I want to know if anybody knows what the default behavior is for the JS bundled with the default ASP.NET MVC5 project is and how to disable what is happening.  Anybody can reproduce.  Fire up VS2013.  Create an ASP.NET MVC5 project.  Add a table.  Dynamically add a row like I am.  It will re-occur.  I am looking for some who can tell me how to stop it from happening.  I looked at the JS files (jquery and bootstrap) and cannot find something - hence the question here

Answer (score 0):

It turns our the error was on my part.

Input of type image submit the form by default - so the AJAX request was running at the same time the form was being submitting.

The way to disble the image input from submitting the form was to have the AddUserListener function return false.

All input images should return false if you do not want them to cause the form to submit.